# Range.Find doesn't work all the time

Tags: excel, vba

I need to get a range based on the position of a cell with a specific text. The following line of code does just that.

```
Sub test()
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set rng = ws2.Cells.Find("asd", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True).Offset(3)
rng.Select
End Sub
```

The problem is that sometimes for some unknown reason, the Range.Find just doesn't want to work and gives out run-time error 91.
When I restart the workbook, sometimes it will still not work and sometimes it will be fixed.
I have no idea why this happens. I cant even try to reproduce the error.
I suspect it is because the cell with the text I am looking for is a merged cell. Could this be the reason?
It still doesn't explain why sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't, though.

I'm using .Select just to test and see if it works.

Question: How do I ensure the Range.Find works every time? (assuming the cell with the text will always exist)

Answer (score 2):

You can test if the Range is Nothing. When the Range is nothing, that means there was nothing Found. And you can't select nothing.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set rng = ws2.Cells.Find("asd", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
    If Not rng  Is Nothing Then 
    rng.Offset(3).Select
    else
    MsgBox("Nothing Found")
    End if 
    End Sub
```

Comment: @SJR Thanks. Forgot about that.

Comment: yes @Moosli but why is it nothing? There is no reason for it to be nothing. That is why im confused.

Comment: it will be nothing if it can't find a match. What you can try is to select the first cell with "ws2.cells(1,1).select" so it will starts with seaching from this point on.